# Cleaning Android project while connected to TFS in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I'm running Eclipse Juno v4.2.1 and just connected to my TFS using [this tutorial](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/connect-eclipse/).

Everything is working fine, but when I need to clean my project, I have to "Check In" twice because the clean deletes and adds the manifest during the clean.  Of course I just want to clean and build without checking in this type of activity.

So, an even more basic question could lead to an answer...how do I "disable" TFS in Eclipse until I'm ready to check in the changes?  How do I set a saved filter or something similar that stops Eclipse from generating an error every time I clean the project while connected to TFS?